# Working archived version of qt source

Tags: git, qt, windows-7-x64

I am trying to build qt for Windows x64 using msvc 2010, and was having trouble with the configure step (building -opengl desktop)

From here:
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/24230

And a few other places, the .zip file of the source available on the QT website doesn't actually build with these options. I've been trying to "git" the repository. I successfully got the base repository with:

```
git clone https://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git qt5
```

But I am having trouble with the "init-repository" step.

1. it always fails during the init-repository call (durring the clone of qtbase, with a "timeout" error, next time it dies I'll add the full error here). I suspect that there is just a network error, but I'm having trouble getting around it. The "init-repository" call I'm using is:

   init-repository --no-webkit --http -f
2. It take FOREVER. I appear to be pulling down at 30-50 KiB/s.

The combination of repeated failures and the long time has got me to start to look for alternatives.

So I'm wondering

1. If anyone knows there is a pre-packaged, already initialized archived version of the working repository out there?
2. Anyone knows how to fix the slow git-problem (could be our host side network, which I can't do anything about).

Comment: My current attempt at a fix is going to be adding a "retry" option in the perl script, we'll see how that goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

You could use a browser and click and download all the modules...

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt5/blobs/master/README.git

Just looking that the GUI frontend of Git, I found some links:

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt5/trees/stable

There is a long listing on this page of all the sub modules with links.  You could go into these and get individual tarballs for the stable version of each.  It could take a while, but it would work.

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt

And on the right side of each page there is a "Download stable as tar.gz".

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, cus it does answer my specific question. See my comments above to see how I solved the root problem.